# Unable to start gui jar at bootup using crontab in Raspberrypi

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Hi I am trying to run a jar based GUI on Raspberry pi. I am able to run it via calling directly from terminal i.e.

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /home/pi/Downloads/GUI1.jar
```

I am succcessfully able to schedule it on cronttab at any given time 
for example

```
28 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/pi/Downloads/GUI1.jar > /home/pi/Downloads/cron.log 2>&1
```

This is also working perfectly

The problem starts when i am trying to run it at boot up. I am using

```
@reboot DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/pi/Downloads/GUI1.jar > /home/pi/Downloads/cron.log 2>&1
```

The cron.log says (Error) and no GUI is shown

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyException in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:68)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
... 5 more
```

Update

I created a simple java app jar file which print outs "Hello World!". Please not this does not have any Graphics in it.

code in crontab

```
@reboot /usr/bin/java -jar /home/oi/Downloads/helloworld.jar > /home/pi/Downloads/cron1.log 2>&1
```

and cron1.log says

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: Do you have a session, a display manager?

Comment: @Mathieu I didnt get you I am using "DISPLAY=:0" for crontab if that u meant.

Comment: Are you using pure X11 display? Probably not, most linux distros have some desktop environment like Gnome/KDE/Unity/Xfce whatever. Instead of crontab, try to configure your GUI app in your desktop environment as auto start app. It probably have such feature.